# cpan command gives the error "Can't locate B.pm in @INC"

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cpan

I wanted to use CPAN to install some Perl packages, but I get the following error when I try to start the CPAN shell:

```
paulzierep@naproxen:~$ cpan
Can't locate B.pm in @INC (you may need to install the B module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /home/paulzierep) at /usr/share/perl/5.22/Safe.pm line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.22/Safe.pm line 34.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.22/CPAN.pm line 56.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.22/CPAN.pm line 56.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.22/App/Cpan.pm line 273.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.22/App/Cpan.pm line 273.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpan line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpan line 9.
```

I can't figure out how to install the missing B module without cpan. I guess this should be installed by default.

I'm using Perl 5.22.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

#### Update

So I set the `PERL5LIB` or `PERL5OPT` to make it find `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/B.pm`, and CPAN runs, but I can not install anything due to the following error

```
cpan[1]> install Log::Log4perl
Reading '/home/paulzierep/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Fri, 30 Sep 2016 06:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Log::Log4perl'
Checksum for /home/paulzierep/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/paulzierep/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
Want /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [5.22.1]
Config says: [x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Log::Log4perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/Config.pm', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz            : make NO
```

So it kind of fixed it and left me with another problem. Any help on this one?

That what I get for:

```
paulzierep@naproxen:~$ perl -E 'say for @INC'
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
/usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
.

paulzierep@naproxen:/home$ perl -MFile::Spec -E 'say for 
File::Spec->path'
/home/paulzierep/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

Comment: You should show your command line...

Comment: No  and I already removed and installed perl again, with apt-get install perl without errors.

Comment: I don't see B.pm in the [perl-modules-5.22](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/perl-modules-5.22/filelist) package, which is where Ubuntu seems to have put the core modules. Maybe they screwed up their packages.

Comment: OK good to know, I'll try an older version then.

Comment: Good hint, I'll try an older version.

Comment: It would be better to leave the system perl alone and use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) or [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) to install your own version in your home directory. Screwing with the system perl can cause other issues.

Comment: OK as a matter of fact, it seems there is no way around the original perl distro, as already pointed out by ThisSuitlsBlackNot, but I mean perlbrew might be nice if you want to run script or whatever with older versions. But cpan should work in any case.

Comment: I found B.pm in the [libperl5.22](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libperl5.22/filelist) package. Do you have that installed? (My advice about perlbrew/plenv still holds.)

Comment: Do you have the `PERL5LIB` or `PERL5OPT` environment variables set? It's very strange that your home directory `/home/paulzierep` is in `@INC`, and the `CPAN` module doesn't use `B`.

Comment: @MarcoS: There isn't a way of changing `@INC` except by modifying the environment or the command line.

Comment: @Paul Zierep, 1) Do you a dir named `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22` on your machine? 2) Do you have a dir named `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1` on your machine? 3) Does `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/B.pm` exist on your machine? 4) Does `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/B.pm` exist on your machine?

Comment: So I do have usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/ and  usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 on my machine, but only 5.22.1 does contain B.pm. I changed the PERL5LIB environement var to usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/ and indeed I am able to open the cpan shell, but ones I try an install now, I get: Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [5.22.1]
Config says: [x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi]; any Idea on this one ?

Comment: It looks like you have two perl installations side-by-side. Did you install another version?

Comment: It seems like that to me too, but I did not install another version. Still this wasn't always my workspace, so this might have been done by somebody. Any Idea how I can get rid of the version which is not systeme dependent ?

Comment: @PaulZierep: You do it by removing the superfluous `perl` from your `PATH` list. Do you know any bash at all?

Comment: Not to much sry, could you elaborate how to remove the  superfluous perl from my PATH ? And in any case this will just leave me with the (B.pm in @INC) error, no ?

Comment: @PaulZierep: If you're not at the system with the problem then we should wait until you get back. Take a break now.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your system, but as you've seen, changing PERL5LIB to include arbitrary is not the way to go!!!

Comment: Ok, leaving the env variables alone, leaves me with the old error, when trying to run cpan, the B.module can not be found. As asked I provided some more infos about the perl version. Any new ideas ?

Comment: Is there anyway to reinstall perl 5.22 ? @Borodin

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For some unknown reason, the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl` was empty. My solution was to reinstall the `libperl5.22` package.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libperl5.22
```

Answer (score 1):

So after having a look on a different systems with pretty similar set-up I found whats the problem with my perl install. It always bugged me, that the 5.22 folder is empty, but still seems to be the folder perl is looking for.

```
paulzierep@naproxen:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl$ ls
5.22  5.22.1 cross-config-5.22.1  debian-config-data-5.22.1
```

In a system with similar set-up I found that the 5.22 was linking to 5.22.1, setting this link solved the problem and perl runs again like a charm.

I additional wanted to point out, that in my reseach I found that the working directory "." seems to be in @INC by default, (http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=375341) therefore I am wondering why it seems so strange to some (@Borodin), that my home directory is there (Any directory is there as long as you start cpan from there).

Also I don't see how perlbrew would help here, besides the fact, that you cannot install it without working perl, I don't see how it would help, when your system perl does not work properly.

Comment: You don't need perl to install plenv.

Comment: Also, `@INC` usually contains `.`, not the absolute path to the current working directory. For example, `perl -E'say "@INC"'` prints `/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .` on my system.

Comment: I don't see where you going @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: I'm responding to two things in your answer: 1) *"I don't see how perlbrew would help here, besides the fact, that you cannot install it without working perl, I don't see how it would help, when your system perl does not work properly."* If the system perl is so completely broken that even the perlbrew install script doesn't run (did you try it?), you can still install plenv. The point of perlbrew and plenv is to install your own versions of perl that are totally independent of the system perl. *(continued)*

Comment: 2) *"I am wondering why it seems so strange to some (@Borodin), that my home directory is there"* `@INC` should contain a literal `.`, not `/home/paulzierep` as the initial error message shows. I'm not sure if this is actually relevant to your problem, I'm just explaining why Borodin thought the error message was strange.

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot  Ahh OK I see, yup this behavior for \@INC is indeed strange than. And I guess plenv might help if the perl is totally screwed. So thank you very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ cpan
    Can't locate File/Spec.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/File/Spec.pm: Permission denied at /usr/share/perl/5.22/CPAN.pm line 10.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.22/CPAN.pm line 10.
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.22/App/Cpan.pm line 273.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.22/App/Cpan.pm line 273.
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpan line 9.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpan line 9.
```

Perl don't looking modules in @INC.

Comment: please add some more detail as to how your answer is solving the OP's question...