# Perl mixed up, Cpan can not install

Tags: perl, cpan, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I wanted to install a package via cpan, but I get the following error:

```
cpan[1]> install Log::Log4perl
Reading '/home/paulzierep/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Fri, 30 Sep 2016 06:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Log::Log4perl'
Checksum for /home/paulzierep/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/paulzierep/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
Want /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [5.22.1]
Config says: [x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Log::Log4perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/Config.pm', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.47.tar.gz            : make NO
```

Well it says to check my perl installation, which is:

```
perl --version

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 58 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Here's `@INC`:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base`

That what I get for:

```
paulzierep@naproxen:~$ perl -E 'say for @INC'
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
/usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
.

paulzierep@naproxen:/home$ perl -MFile::Spec -E 'say for File::Spec->path'
/home/paulzierep/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

Comment: As this question in not related to programming but rather to system configuration, I would recommend to address the question to one of the more system-related sites on SO network, for example unix/linux, serverfault or (regarding that tag) **askubuntu**.

Comment: @syck The question is fine here. From the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "if your question generally covers…a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or **software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development…then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Is this the same version of cpan you [asked about yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39773525) that choked because it couldn't find B.pm? If so, you should [edit] your question to show how you got past that issue.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it is indeed, as a matter of fact I am pretty new here and do not get how to edit the quastion.

Comment: Just click the "edit" button at the bottom of your question (or the edit link in my last comment). It's a good idea to edit your question with additional information as you go, since the comments can become unwieldy after a while. For example, you could add the information that brian d foy asked about as well as a link to yesterday's question and an explanation of what you've done so far.

Comment: So I changed the old one, will delete this one then. Well due to the answer this does not work anymore,...changed the other post anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've previously mentioned adding a directory to `PERL5LIB` you shouldn't have added. Please reverse this change and this problem will go away.

Comment: By reversing this, I come out a a previous error, when trying to open cpan: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773525/cpan-command-gives-the-error-cant-locate-b-pm-in-inc?noredirect=1#comment66887380_39773525

Comment: @Paul Zierep, Of course you do. You still haven't fixed that error. I'm just telling you how to fix this one.

Answer (score 4):

This typically happens when the perl you invoke looks in library directories that other perls left behind. Part of the error is:

> Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
>   architecture they are running on.

Start investigating there. Find out where it's finding the mismatched Config.pm and fix that issue. Running `perl -V` to see what's in `@INC` will help.

Beyond that you'll have to tell us a lot more about your setup.

Comment: The \@INC looks in   \@INC:
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
    /usr/share/perl/5.22
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
It finds the Config.pm file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/ only because I put the path into PERL5LIB="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/" . If I do not set the env it can not run cpan at all.

Comment: @PaulZierep that PERL5LIB setting is causing your problem then; somehow the cpan command you are doing (which you don't show :( ) is using a different perl.  Try just `perl -MCPAN -eshell`

Comment: @ysth I removed the PERL5LIB path, but then I can not run cpan at all: Error Can't locate B.pm in \@INC, like my old poste: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773525/why-does-the-default-cpan-on-ubuntu-16-04-give-the-error-cant-locate-b-pm-in?noredirect=1#comment66880382_39773525

Comment: @PaulZierep do you get that with `perl -MCPAN -eshell`?  It looks to me like when you just type `cpan` it is using a different perl than the one when you type `perl`, and that other perl is incomplete.

Comment: @ysth I am out of office now, will look into this on tuesday (german holiday on monday), thx a lot.

Comment: Add all clarifications to the original question please :)

Comment: perl -MCPAN -eshell gives me the same error as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773525/cpan-command-gives-the-error-cant-locate-b-pm-in-inc

Answer (score 1):

You should really take another look at the comments on your previous question

[*Why does the default cpan on Ubuntu 16.04 give the error "Can't locate B.pm in @INC"?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773525/why-does-the-default-cpan-on-ubuntu-16-04-give-the-error-cant-locate-b-pm-in)

where I observed that your `@INC`contains your home directory `/home/paulzierep` in the *last* position

I asked whether the environment variables `PERL5LIB` or `PERL5OPT` were set, and your only response says

> I changed the PERL5LIB environement var to usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/ and indeed I am able to open the cpan shell, but ones I try an install now, I get: Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the architecture they are running on

I don't know what you have done to get your home directory at the end of `@INC`. Both `PERL5LIB` and the `-I` command-line options use `unshift` instead of `push`, and add locations to the *start* of the `@INC` array

It's quite possible to build a new perl image with your home directory in `@INC` by default, but surely you would have said so if that is what you had done?

Let me be clear: `PERL5LIB` and `PERL5OPT` should be *undefined* for normal operation of perl

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear, the PERL5LIB or PERL5OPT were not set. I am sure I did not build a new perl image, as I have no idea how to do that. Neither do I know why my home directory is in the @INC.

Comment: So in case PERL5LIB and PERL5OPT are undefined, the can't locate B.pm error is still there.

Comment: @PaulZierep: Your previous question shows that `/home/paulzierep` is in perl's `@INC` array. It seems likely that someone called Paul Zierep made that happen. What do you see when you run `perl -E 'say for @INC'` after making sure all of the `PERL*` environment variables are cleared?

Comment: @PaulZierep: Also, what does `perl -MFile::Spec -E 'say for File::Spec->path'`

Comment: this sounds reasonable, but still I don't see how I could have done that, I am out of office now, will poste the result of perl -E say 'for \@INC' on tuesday (german holiday on monday), thx

Comment: @PaulZierep: I think you should start a new question on Tuesday and link both of your preceding ones. Please don't add new information to either of the old ones unless it is to fix incorrect information, and even then you should leave your old text intact. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulZierep: Note that there is no backslash in `perl -E 'say for @INC'`

Comment: @PaulZierep: ***Happy Unification Day!!***

Comment: thx a lot, if I get this fixed on tuesday, would be the the perfect present for this special day. I will poste accordingly.

Comment: As a matter of fact the @INC always shows the current working dict (in my case), so it showed the path where I opened cpan --/home/paulzierep. But still I am wondering how I can change the error mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773525/cpan-command-gives-the-error-cant-locate-b-pm-in-inc

Answer (score 0):

So after deleting the perl related environment variables I came back to my previous error post [cpan command gives the error "Can't locate B.pm in @INC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773525/cpan-command-gives-the-error-cant-locate-b-pm-in-inc?noredirect=1#comment66887380_39773525). 
Which I managed to solve, so I assume this answers this post then as well.