# Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the architecture they are running on

Tags: perl, apt, locallib

I am trying to install a perl-based program using my system perl and local::lib. The program has several dependencies, which I want to install with apt, e.g., `libalien-wxwidgets-perl`, `libwx-perl`,`libgraphics-gnuplotif-perl`, etc. I have installed local::lib with cpan and added the line to my ~/.zshrc, but it seems that it's not working. When I run `perl -I. Build.PL`, it says I don't have permissions and I need to run `sudo perl -I. Build.PL`.

In this case, this is the error, but I will also get other permissions related errors. Since the directory is not below `~/perl5`, I am thinking this is because `local::lib` isn't working:

```
Can't create '_build/runtime_params': Permission denied at /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Module/Build/Notes.pm line 110.
```

Perl also cannot find these packages installed by apt. On a fresh system, with local::lib installed manually, `perl -I. Build.PL` works without sudo, and perl finds, for example, `libwx-perl`.

so I tried to install local::lib manually:

```
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000029.tar.gz
tar xvf local-lib-2.000029.tar.gz
cd local-lib-2.000029
perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap
```

but I get this error:

```
Have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
Want /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [perl-base]
Config says: [x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for local::lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

I think this has something to do with why perl can't find the packages installed by apt and also why local::lib doesn't work. What does "Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the architecture they are running on" mean? Could this have to do with the fact that I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (rather than doing a fresh reinstall)?

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793096/perl-mixed-up-cpan-can-not-install), I have deleted all `PERL5LIB` lines from my ~/.zshrc, but I still get the error.

Here is perl -V:

```
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/home/joseph/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/user/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/user/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/user/perl5"
  @INC:
    /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/5.34.0/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/5.34.0
    /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34
    /usr/share/perl/5.34
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

I am trying to get it so that my system install of perl 5.34 can both run without `sudo` and can find the dependencies I've installed by apt.

Comment: *"I am trying to install a perl-based program ..."* : Can you give a minimal example of the program?

Comment: *"When I run perl -I. Build.PL, it says I don't have permissions"* Can you share the exact error message you get?

Comment: Provide the exact error message, as well as the output of `which perl` `which cpan` and `head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"`

Comment: @ikegami I will provide the exact error message shortly. The output of `which perl` is `/usr/bin/perl`, `which cpan` is `/usr/bin/perl/cpan`, and `head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"` is `/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I updated the question.

Comment: @gannex *"When I run perl -I. Build.PL, it says I don't have permissions.. [..] Can't create '_build/runtime_params': Permission denied"* I think it is trying to create the `_build` folder in the current directory. What is the directory you are running this from? What is its permissions?

Comment: *"sudo perl -I. Build.PL"* sudo user will probably not know anything about local::lib installed by your regular user. That may explain some of the errors?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I'm trying to install it into my home directory. I think what is happening is that local::lib is not working due to inconsistencies in my perl install. On a fresh install of  Ubuntu 22.04 on another computer, I can install local::lib without getting the error in the title and `perl -I. Build.PL` runs with no complaints.

Comment: Maybe try to find out more about this error message: *"Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the architecture they are running on."* It comes when you run `perl Makefile.PL`, see line 2757 in `ExtUtils/MM_any.pm` : https://metacpan.org/release/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.70/source/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm#L2757

Comment: *"When I run perl -I. Build.PL, it says I don't have permissions.. [..] Can't create '_build/runtime_params': Permission denied ... I'm trying to install it into my home directory*" : It might also be that you first tried to install with `sudo perl -I. Build.PL` and that created the directory `_build` with root ownership. When you later try to run `perl -I. Build.PL` without sudo, the `_build` directory is still there and owned by root. The solution might be to delete the `_build` folder as root first (`sudo rm -rf _build`)

Comment: Re "*The output of*", So you are using the system `perl`, and you are using the cpan for the `system`. All is consistent (good) there. /// I concur with HH. You've created files as root but you're no longer root, and that's causing problems. Remove `_build` using sudo to solve the problem.

Comment: @HåkonHægland you were right about `_build`! I didn't realize it creates that directory. `perl -I. Build.PL` now runs without sudo.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the program repo has a directory called `blib`, which always has some root ownership, even if I do `perl -I. Build.PL` without sudo. Also, it looks like I still can't install the program because perl can't find modules I installed with apt. So I'm back to square one.

Comment: @gannex "*looks like the program repo has a directory called blib, which always has some root ownership"* Try to delete that `blib` folder. It is regenerated when you run the build script anyway

Comment: @HåkonHægland I tried that, but it always creates a file somewhere inside `blib` called `Config.pm` and when I run `perl -I. Build test`, it says `Permission denied at ....Config.pm line 505`